# Trying to get the Selected checkbox values with the ID value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

**Below is the Model**

```
public class M_ProjectType
{
    public Int16 ProjectTypeID { get; set; }
    public String ProjectType { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
    public Decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

**Below is View Model**

```
public class VM_Project
{
    public string[] SkillID { get; set; }

    public List<M_ProjectType> ProjectType { get; set; }
}
```

**Below is Get Action method. here I am getting the data for projects that will be sent to View Model**

```
[HttpGet, Route("Project")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Project()
{
    var projectTypes = (await _projectTypes.ProjectTypesList()).Value;

    var list = new List<M_ProjectType>();
    foreach (var item in projectTypes)
    {
        list.Add(new M_ProjectType
            {
                Cost = item.Cost,
                Description = item.Description,
                IsActive = item.IsActive,
                IsChecked = false,
                ProjectType = item.ProjectType,
                ProjectTypeID = item.ProjectTypeID
            }
        );
    }
    var project = new VM_Project
    {
        ProjectType = list
    };

    return View(project);
}
```

**Below is Razor View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ProjectType)
{
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>

            <input type="hidden" value="@item.ProjectTypeID" name="ProjectTypeID" />
            <tr>
                <td style="width:5%">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => item.IsChecked, new { @class = "tableflat" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(i => item.ProjectTypeID)
                </td>
                <td style="width:10%">@item.ProjectType</td>
                <td style="width:80%">@item.Description</td>
                <td style="width:5%"><b>$@item.Cost</b></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

**Below is Post Action Method**

```
[HttpPost, Route("Project")]
public ActionResult Project(VM_Project project)
{
    return View();
}
```

> Question: I am getting project.ProjectType = null. Any suggestion why
>   this is happening ?

Comment: Where did you bind projectType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using EditorTemplates.

1. Create a folder named `EditorTemplates` in you `Views/Shared` direcotry.
2. Create a partial view based on your type i.e. `M_ProjectType.cshtml`
3. Put your markup that you use in `foreach` loop in `M_ProjectType.cshtml` file

   ```
   @model M_ProjectType
   <table class="table table-striped">
   <tbody>

       <tr>
           <td style="width:5%">
               @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => i.IsChecked, new { @class = "tableflat" })
               @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.ProjectTypeID)
           </td>
           <td style="width:10%">@Model.ProjectType
           @Html.HiddenFor(i=>i.ProjectType)
           </td>
           <td style="width:80%">@Model.Description</td>
           <td style="width:5%"><b>$@Model.Cost</b></td>
       </tr>

   </tbody>
   ```
4. Then render your editor template in your form like (note: no `foreach` loop)

   ```
   @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.ProjectType)
   ```

You should get correct model binded to your html elements back in controller.

Comment: Where should I place the for each loop ?

Comment: No foreach loop required. Just place `@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.ProjectType)` inside your Html.BeginForm or whatever your form element is. It will iterate itself.

Comment: I have 6 records in the element for iteration. But this is not even iterating for single time.

Comment: Assuming that you have all records in `ProjectType` list, try putting just `@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.ProjectType)` in your view.

Comment: I was using incorrect partial View name. Now, I created the same name as of class. Now the Iteration is happening 6 times. but I am still not able to post array to controller action method.

Comment: Have you put it inside the `form` element? Do you reach to your `HttpPost` method (breakpoint) when submitting form?

Comment: Any possible suggtion of possible here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737344/unobtrusive-validation-for-dropdown-list-with-multiple-selection-option

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ProjectType)
{
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>

                <tr>
                <td style="width:5%">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => item.IsChecked, new { @class = "tableflat" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(i => item.ProjectTypeID, new { @Value = item.ProjectTypeID})
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Are you getting ProjectTypeID successfully?

Comment: I have edited for projectTypeID, please try it
We need to specify Value for hidden value also

Comment: Sorry this post is not useful.

Comment: This must be work. it's working in me. Try to put debugger on hidden field and check are you getting value